# Maximum shortest path problem

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I have the following problem. You have a graph and every edge has a certain set of possible weights. The question is to find the assignment of those weight which will maximize the shortest path.

In other words, for every edge $e \in E$ you have possible weights $w_e^k$ and costs $c_e^k$. The problem is to find such assignment of the weights (i.e. for $e_1$ you have $k=1$, for $e_2$ you have $k=4$, for $e_3$ you have $k=1$ that means for the first edge you chose the first weight, for the second the fourth for the thirds the first and so on). For the fixed weight assignment you find the shortest path. The goal is to find the assignment which maximizes the shortest path. Of course, one would say just pick the maximum weights through all of possible ones, so let's add a budgetary constraint for this case.

Clarification what I mean by the shortest path : in addition to all the data above, you are given the source and sink - starting and ending vertices. You look at all paths between them, selecting the one with minimum weight. You can assume the weights are positive or paths are simple.

So far I tried to modify the classical MIP model for the shortest path, but with no correct solution.

I would appreciate the help and ideas.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Is there some additional bound on $\sum_k c_e^k$?

Comment: Just added that we have a budgetary constraint on selecting the weights. Otherwise, there is a trivial greedy solution to choose the maximum weight for every edge, this will guarantee the maximum shortest path.

Comment: If your graph is arranged in a single line (that is, node $i$ is connected only to nodes $i+1$ and $i-1$), then this problem reduces to the knapsack problem, so it's at least NP-hard.  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I would be glad to have a MIP formulation to this problem as the ultimate goal. However, a DP algorithm is also acceptable if there is one.

Comment: What do you mean by a shortest path? An Hamiltonian path linking two prescribed vertices? And lenght is the sum of weights of the edges in the path?

Comment: You are given two vertices, the starting and the ending. The shortest path is between those two. I'l add this to the question, good observation.